# Short Link SDK iOs

Tags: ios, short-url

I'm looking for an sdk/easy way to create a short link programmatically, preferably via a known service such as bitly.com / tinurl.com
The only way I've found doing this is with McAfee's beta short-link service, but it is unknown, and I want the link to be from a known service.

Does anybody know such way?

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be overkill for your project, but do take a look at ShareKit. The main download page is at http://getsharekit.com/install/#download .

If you do end up using ShareKit then I suggest you use forked version below since it has quite a few bug fixes.

https://github.com/polydice/ShareKit

Comment: ShareKit is indeed pretty-heavy. there's no part that can be ripped-off of it ( is that ok by the license? ) to get only the specific functionality?